# Einwortumschreibung für "unabsichtlich ignorieren"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request, synonym

Gibt es ein einzelnes Wort für oben das genannte "unabsichtlich ignorieren"?

"ignorieren" ist ja eigentlich als willentliches nicht beachten definiert, mit meist (sehr) negativer Bedeutung.
Jedoch fällt mir kein Wort ein das man stattdessen benutzen könnte und google hat für mich nichts ergeben, bzw weiß ich nicht wie ich danach noch suchen könnte.

Ein Beispiel hierfür wäre wenn man jemandem etwas sagt, dieser dies aber überhaupt nicht hört (aus welchen Gründen auch immer ohne von anderem übertönt zu werden) und dann nicht auf das Gesagte reagiert. Die angesprochene Person ignoriert dann unabsichtlich erstere.

Ich möchte nicht unbedingt das "spezielle" überhört oder übersehen sondern würde gerne wissen ob es ein allgemeineres  Wort dafür gibt.

Comment: _nicht wahrnehmen_ vielleicht.

Comment: Etwas mehr Kontext würde es leichter machen, deine Frage zu beantworten. Bitte nenne ein oder zwei konkrete Beispiele.

Answer (score 11):

Mein Vorschlag wäre:

> übersehen

als "nicht willentliches Nichtbeachten" mit neutraler Bedeutung.

Comment: habe meine Frage  editiert, würde gerne wissen ob es etwas "generelles" dafür gibt

Comment: @Wattefugg Ich finden "übersehen" und "überhören" sind zwei sehr schöne Verben, die das, was du suchst, sehr gut zum Ausdruck bringen. Das in einer anderen Antwort erwähnte "entgehen" finde ich eher so lala.

Comment: die Wörter mögen zwar ganz gut passen sind aber gebunden an den jeweiligen Sinn und ich wollte wissen ob es ein allgemeines Wort gibt, da diese  für mich persönlich die einzelnen unzufriedenstellend sind. aber wenn es kein passendes Wort im deutschen gibt ist das wohl einfach eine Lücke in der Sprache, wo es doch sonst für alles mindestens ein Wort gibt das nicht speziell ist oder umschreibt

Answer (score 8):

Das aus mangelnder Aufmerksamkeit erfolgende Übersehen gibts auch für die Ohren:

> [überhören](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueberhoeren_ignorieren_verpassen)

---

Nachdem du die Frage geändert hast, kann ich nur auf das allgemeinere, von LangLangC schon genannte

> [entgehen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/entgehen) *(von jemandem, etwas unbemerkt bleiben)*

verweisen.

> *Nicht hören:* Seine Bemerkung über den Chef ist mir entgangen.
>
> *Nicht sehen:* Das Kleingedruckte ist mir entgangen.
>
> *Nicht fühlen:* Dass der Dieb in meine Gesäßtasche gegriffen hat, ist mir entgangen.
>
> *Nicht riechen:* Beim Spaziergang hat meine Frau mich so zugetextet, dass mir der Duft des Rosengartens entgangen ist.
>
> *Nicht schmecken:* Das Fußballspiel hat mich so gefesselt, dass mir das fehlende Suppensalz entgangen ist.

Comment: habe meine Frage  editiert, würde gerne wissen ob es etwas "generelles" dafür gibt

Answer (score 2):

Käme zwar auf den Kontext an, aber unabsichtlich ignorieren ist bei flüchigem Blick auf die Etymologie schon fast ein wenig oxymoronisch doppelt gemoppelt:

> Ignorant m. ‘wer etw. beharrlich nicht zur Kenntnis nehmen, nicht wissen will’, im 16. Jh. aus lat. īgnōrāns (Genitiv īgnōrantis), Part. Präs. zu lat. īgnōrāre **‘etw. nicht kennen oder nicht kennen *wollen’***, entlehnt. Ignoranz f. ‘Unkenntnis, Unwissenheit’, Entlehnung (16. Jh.) von gleichbed. lat. īgnōrantia. ignorieren Vb. ‘nicht zur Kenntnis nehmen wollen, übersehen’ (18. Jh.), aus lat. īgnōrāre, vielleicht unter Einfluß von frz. ignorer.
>   <sub>[DWDS: ignorieren](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ignorieren)</sub>

*Ignorieren* hat jedenfalls in meinem Wortverständnis und in meiner Wortverwendung auch keineswegs zwangsläufig die Mitbedeutung: *willentlich* ignorieren. Da die Bedeutungsverengung recht weit verbreitet zu sein scheint, sind Missverständnisse durchaus nicht ausgeschlossen.

Eine Möglichkeit wäre also einfach eine heute vielleicht etwas altertümliche Verwendung von *ignorieren* allein wieder durch gehäuften Gebrauch durchzusetzen als neutrale Beschreibung des *nicht wissen* (ob nun mit oder ohne volitionalem Aspekt).

Falls das nun schon vorgeschlagene und ebenfalls als absichtlich wie unabsichtlich verstehbare *übersehen* oder *entgehen* benutzt werden sollen:

> Die habe ich völlig übersehen.

kann aber je nach Betonung und Kontext auch leicht im Sinne von *schneiden* interpretiert werden.
<sub>Man stelle sich einen bayerischen Politiker in Berlin vor…</sub>

Man beachte, dass zum Beispiel das DWDS auch für *übersehen* erst an Stelle II,3 die gewünschte Bedeutung auslistet:

> II:  übersieht (Präsens), übersah, ›hat‹, übersehen
>   3. etw., jmdn. unabsichtlich nicht sehen, nicht beachten, nicht berücksichtigen
>   <sub>[DWDS: übersehen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/%C3%BCbersehen)</sub>

Bei

> Der ist mir entgangen.

ist das hingegen nur mit sehr süffisantem Unterton als "mit Absicht" zu verstehen.

> 2. ⟨etw. entgeht jmdm., einer Sache⟩etw. fällt jmdm. nicht auf, wird von jmdm. nicht bemerkt
>      <sub>[DWDS: entgehen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/entgehen)</sub>

Comment: Es stimmt zwar, das *ignorieren* aus dem lateinischen Wort für *nicht wissen* entstanden ist, aber diese Bedeutung hat dieses Wort im Deutschen schon lange nicht mehr. Wenn du sagst *»Ich ignoriere viele Paragraphen des Strafgesetzes«* wird niemand verstehen *»Ich kenne viele Paragraphen des Strafgesetzes nicht«.* Jeder wird davon ausgehen, dass du meinst: *»Ich missachte viele Paragraphen des Strafgesetzes«.* Und das ist wohl ein eklatant großer Unterschied. Viel Spaß dabei, wenn du im Alleingang versuchst, die alte Bedeutung wiederzubeleben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wie gesagt, eine gewisse Bedeutungsverengung ist zweifellos d, nicht zuletzt in den Lexika. Aber ich meine in "Oh, das muss ich völlig ignoriert haben" eine gewisse Unabsichtlichkeit auch allgemeinverständlich hören zu können.

Comment: Wenn mir jemand sagt »das muss ich völlig ignoriert haben«, dann höre ich da nur Sarkasmus raus. Denn ignorieren ist etwas, dass man **nur** absichtlich machen kann. Das ist nichts, was einem ohne Absicht passieren könnte. Wenn man ohne Absicht nicht in Kenntnis von etwas gelangt ist, dann hat man das nicht ignoriert, sonder *übersehen* (wenn man es eigentlich mitbekommen haben sollte), oder man weiß es schlichtweg nicht. Aber *ignorieren* bedeutet (zumindest meiner Auffassung nach) dasselbe wie *missachten*.

Answer (score 1):

**Verpassen.**

Sowohl akustische, als auch optische Reize lassen sich verpassen und im allgemeinen wird damit Unabsichtliches ausgedrückt.

> Ich muss die Frage verpasst haben.
>
> Am Gepäckband hat sie unseren Koffer glatt verpasst.

Aber es wird auch unspezifisch bzgl. des Informationskanals eingesetzt, im Sinne von "nicht mitbekommen":

> Dass Dr. Gruber verzogen ist habe ich verpasst.